# Can I post this kind of a question on (Meta) Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Please read this post and carefully understand it, because it is about a turning point in my life.

For some time, I am in an interest of making a group of software engineers(Java)/SD students(Java) and working together with them, creating free apps and commercial apps as a team (OK, don't laugh :D). Specially, I would like to join with people who are in my age (I am 22) and who had never got a chance to show their talents to the world, but who are really talented. And, I would like to join 2 or three highly experienced software engineers to out group to advice us.  After joining the members, all other communications will happen via our Facebook page, Google/Yahoo group, and email, until we put up our own site. If we create a free app, it is OK, if we create a non free app, the profit will be served between members in an agreed way.

Can I put this kind of invitation up on Stack Overflow or in this meta?

Comment: No, this would not be on topic in either place.  There is no site on the Stack Exchange on which this would be appropriate.  It could be discussed in chat, but you'd have to find a room that was amenable to what *might* be construed as advertising.

Comment: Instead of criticism, people may direct users to the right place, i guess...

Comment: Looks to me like you already have.

Comment: A preemptive comment for you - [Downvotes are slightly different here on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: OK all. Thanks for the replies...

Comment: Please visit this question [What Stack Overflow is not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not) ?

Comment: @razlebe: I already have what?

Comment: Guys, I feels so bad because of this down votes. :(

Comment: I know people in certain cultures love to make friends through Stack Overflow, but we're not a social networking site or a chat site. Please don't share your personal contact info here.

Comment: @Sepala In posting this question, you've already essentially posted your invitation.

Comment: @razlebe: wow!! I didn't meant to do that, but it has happened! wow! It is just a happening guys, I am not a talented marketer! LOL :D

Answer (score 10):

No, not on Stack Overflow, and not, as far as I know, anywhere on the Stack Exchange sites.

Stack Exchange does Q&A. The sites are not forums, discussion boards, or meetup planners (except maybe for [careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/)).

You could possibly use the chat area to build a group, but posting this as a question anywhere would be off-topic.

Comment: OK, chat area allowed?

Comment: Depends on the chat room. Some might accept this type of thing, some not. Don't just drop in to a room and drop your question. You could create a room just for that once you have the required privilege. But I'm not sure Stack Exchange is the best fit, you should also look at other online communities (forums & discussion boards, startup resources, etc.)

Answer (score 7):

No, you cannot. We [aren't a job site or social network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128556)

SO is for coding-related Q&A, an invitation isn't Q&A. This meta is for discussion *about* SO, so an invitation for members isn't good either.

Go to http://careers.stackoverflow.com if you want awesome programmers! (It's a paid service for employers)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not seeking for programmers like that. I am seeking for people in my age, to make a nice group, one day we can be a BIG group, just like mozilla :) (don't laugh, I have lot of dreams)

Answer (score 3):

[careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com), [linkedin.com](http://linkedin.com), etc. and even [facebook](http://facebook.com) and [twitter](http://twitter.com) are solutions for you. NOT meta.stackoverflow.com or stackoverflow.com or any other SX site.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunatly, linkedin is not what I am seeking for. FB and twitter might be, but I can't make sure whether they are programmers or not and it will take a very long time in thise sites

Answer (score 1):

Simple Answer will be, No, you can't ask such question here. Stack Overflow is just a Question and Answer site which are related to relative sites.

You should read this point of faq, **[May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here ?](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion)**

The Question you are asking is a kind of business advertisement. Such questions are not allowed, However you can advertise your business or idea on Stack Overflow which is visible to users < 200 reputation on their Question head and between the two answers.